# Saveas issue Overwrite existing file ( Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro that is correct except for the `SaveAs` gives me an error if I click `No` or `Cancel`,if I click `yes` is working fine.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges

Application.DisplayAlert =True
```

But when I come to `SaveAs` part I get the following error when I select `No` to the save.
 Excel message: **A file named " ......... " already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it**? I click 'No' or `cancel` and get the run time error 1004 ....
Method `SaveAs` of object `_Workbook` failed.

I don't want to use the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, because I want the user to be aware that there is a file already named the same.

1. Why do I get this error? Why can't I select 'No'
2. What other option do I have to display that the file is already
   there and select `No` or `Cancel`and not get the run-time error.?

Comment: you can always put On Error Resume Next

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this method.

I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it. Still if you do then simply ask :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim fName As Variant

    '~~> Offer user to Save the file at a particular location
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

    '~~> Check if it is a valid entry
    If fName <> False Then
        '~~> Check before hand if the file exists
        If Not Dir(fName) <> "" Then
            '~~> If not then save it
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName
        Else
            '~~> Trap the error and ignore it
            On Error Resume Next
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else '<~~ If user presses Save
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, _
                FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, _
                ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Siddharth, I want  when user click 'no' button then  save as dialog box should appear.

Comment: You can use a boolean variable to check if the user pressed "No" and then loop back :)

Comment: How can I check that?