# Using VB.Net Read from file, edt cells and finally save

Tags: vb.net, save, excel-2007, savechanges

```
    Public Function SetInfo(ByRef place As String, ByRef name As String) As Boolean
    Dim Completed As Boolean = False
    Dim MyExcel As New Excel.Application

    Dim myworkbook As New Excel.Workbook

    myworkbook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(place)

    MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(place)


    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim finish As Boolean = False

    MyExcel.Sheets("Sheet1").activate()
    MyExcel.Range("B1").Activate()



    Do
        If MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value = name Then
            Exit Do

        Else

            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

        End If
    Loop


    Do
        If MyExcel.ActiveCell.Text = "" Then

            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value = "attended"
            MsgBox("Wrote.")
            Exit Do
        Else
            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate()
        End If
    Loop

    myworkbook.Save()
    MyExcel.Workbooks.Close()

    MyExcel = Nothing
    Return finish
End Function
```

I will explain this code.

Start with Cell B1, and whenever the cell doesn't include what I wanted, the activate cell go right.

And if the cell is what I wanted, it goes down until program find blank space.

And in this process, there's no problem.

In saving process, it occurs problem.

If I delete these section

```
    Dim myworkbook As New Excel.Workbook

    myworkbook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(place)
```

and

```
    myworkbook.Save()
```

"Something has been change, will you save it?" this Excel messagebox comes out.

And I don't want to see the messagebox and I want to save it in my program.

What should I do?

PS.Sry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 myworkbook.Save()

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Or you can use .saveAs()
msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx

see: [Saveas issue Overwrite existing file ( Excel VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967659/saveas-issue-overwrite-existing-file-excel-vba)

```
 Sub Sample()
            Dim fName As Object

            '~~> Offer user to Save the file at a particular location
            fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

            '~~> Check if it is a valid entry
            If fName <> False Then
                '~~> Check before hand if the file exists
                If Not Dir(fName) <> "" Then
                    '~~> If not then save it
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName
                Else
                    '~~> Trap the error and ignore it
                    On Error Resume Next
                    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    Else '<~~ If user presses Save
                        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename:=fName, _
                        FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, _
                        ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```