# Exporting to CSV

Tags: vba, excel

I want to export to CSV and not "Save As", so create a button which will be enabled by a macro. When clicked, it should create a .csv file of the first sheet in a specified directory and also specified name. And my original worksheet should be preserved and not Saved As.

Comment: Why not do a save copy as csv?

Comment: Saveas csv will only convert one sheet to csv

Comment: @Davesexcel OP is only talking about one sheet and hasn't really given any  reason for wanting to reinvent this particular wheel.

Comment: That's right , so there is no reason not to use saveas..........

Comment: Maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21568837/4996248

Comment: @JohnColeman, Save as will make the current file to be saved as that, which will result in problems while saving the sheet as *xlsm*.

Answer (score 3):

If the point is keeping the original workbook untouched then why not get creative. We can copy the sheet to another workbook and the save as .csv

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportOneSheet()

    Const strFILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\tes.csv"

    Dim shToExport As Worksheet

    ' Set the sheet to copy
    Set shToExport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Make a copy of the sheet, when called without argument
    ' it will create a new workbook
    shToExport.Copy
    Set shToExport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' If the file exists the delete it. This will esure that
    ' there is no previous file so the replace file thing will not show
    If Not Dir$(strFILE_NAME, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
        Kill strFILE_NAME
    End If

    ' Use Save As and your original workbook stays untouched.
    shToExport.SaveAs strFILE_NAME, XlFileFormat.xlCSV
    shToExport.Parent.Close True

End Sub
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Let me try this, will get back to you if this works.

Comment: Well, this works perfectly bro, as intended. **Thanks a lot**. Would be even more glad if there was a way to skip the *Yes* or *No* buttons for **Replacement of the existing** file. There might be a way through, right?

Comment: I modified the Answer to delete the file is there is one already. So now you will not be prompted to replace the file.

Comment: Some error in this part **If Not Dir$(strFILE_NAME, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then**

Comment: note that the full path to the file is now in this constant strFILE_NAME make sure to change it to your computer file path.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have commas embedded in cells, this may be enough:

```
Sub CSV_Maker()
   Dim r As Range
   Dim sOut As String, k As Long, M As Long
   Dim N As Long, nFirstRow As Long, nLastRow As Long

   Sheets(1).Select

   ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
   nFirstRow = r.Row
   Dim separator As String
   separator = ","

   MyFilePath = "C:\TestFolder\"
   MyFileName = "whatever"
   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(MyFilePath & MyFileName & ".csv", True)

   For N = nFirstRow To nLastRow
       k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(N, 1).EntireRow)
       sOut = ""
       If k = 0 Then
           sOut = vbCrLf
       Else
           M = Cells(N, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           For mm = 1 To M
               sOut = sOut & Cells(N, mm).Value & separator
           Next mm
           sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 1)
       End If
       a.writeline (sOut)
   Next

   a.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: This helps mate. But the one mentioned by **Fred** above, is damn simpler.