# Runtime error '438' when using procedure to export Sheet1 to CSV

Tags: vba, macos, excel, csv

From this [How to browse for save directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568837/excel-macro-export-sheet-to-csv-and-browse-for-save-directory/41190468), I have used the following code to export Sheet1 to CSV file with browser file for saving :

Here the function that I used :

```
Sub ExportCSV()

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String

MyFileName = "Base_donnees" & "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")

If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"

Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "" '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker.
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:

With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With

End Sub
```

And when I push on "Export to CSV" button, I get the following error:

[image: Error image]

and the debug window shows:

[image: Debug window]

As you can see, I get a:

> Runtime error '438' : Object doesn't support this property or method

Which method or property have I got to use? I am using Excel 2011 for MacOS.

VBA editor looks like this:

[image: VBA editor browse]

Comment: This post my help:[Application.Filedialog support in Mac excel 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960873/application-filedialog-support-in-mac-excel-2011)

Comment: Here is how to select folders with Mac VBA: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac017.htm

Comment: select folder on Mac , refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/office/hh710200(v=office.14).aspx)