# Save active sheet to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want a button to save the active sheet to a new workbook prompting the user for filename and path. It needs to save as a .xlsm

I have this but have this issue.

1. If filename already exist it prompts to debug and will open the vba code.

   ```
   Private Sub SaveBarList_Click()
   ActiveSheet.Copy
   With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   .Copy
   .PasteSpecial xlValues
   .PasteSpecial xlFormats
   End With
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Dim DTAddress As String
   DTAddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Application.PathSeparator
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Application.GetSaveAsFilename
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: To use named arguments eg:`fileSaveName` you need to use `:=` instead of just `=`. The argument is also just `Filename` in my version of excel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saveas issue Overwrite existing file ( Excel VBA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967659/saveas-issue-overwrite-existing-file-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my idea:

```
Sub SaveAsMacro()

    Dim strDir As String

    'Show standard save as dialogue box
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strDir
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Basically gets the file name first (and a warning pops up if overwriting), then bulldozers ahead and saves no matter what (after switching warnings off).

Alternatively if you don't care for the warning and just wanted to suppress it, you can more simply use your original code with warnings switched off:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Application.GetSaveAsFilename
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: If I wanted to save it as .xls what do I need to change?

Comment: I think if you type it as the file name extension in the dialogue box it should do it?

Comment: It will but right now it defaults to .xlsx and wanted to make it default to .xls

Comment: Not sure. if you're using 2007 or later, I think it will always do this. You could do a work around if you're using the two step method I shared (take the last four xlsx characters and change to xls before saving), but not sure how to change the default.